# How do I add a history function to my calculator program using multidimensional arrays?

Tags: c#

I started to learn C# a few days ago and I'm currently playing around with simple programs. At the moment, I made a simple calculator using Visual Studios 2015. I want to add a history function to my program. I want it to store the history of the last 10 calculations by using multidimensional arrays and allow the user to print out their history, but I am too inexperienced with this. Can someone give me pointers? It would be helpful to further my understanding of C#.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            do
            {
                double result;

                Console.WriteLine("\nType your first number: ");
                string stringFirstNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                double firstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(stringFirstNumber);

                Console.WriteLine("Type your second number: ");
                string stringSecondNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                double secondNumber = Convert.ToDouble(stringSecondNumber);

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the operation + (addition), - (subtraction), * (multiplication), / (division), ^ (exponent), or % (modulus): ");
                string stringOperation = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (stringOperation)
                {
                    case "+":
                        result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
                        Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + " " + stringOperation + " " + secondNumber + " = " + result);
                        break;
                    case "addition":
                        result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
                        Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber + " = " + result);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
                        Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + " " + stringOperation + " " + secondNumber + " = " + result);
                        break;
                    case "subraction":
                        result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
                        Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + " - " + secondNumber + " = " + result);
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
                        Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + " " + stringOperation + " " + secondNumber + " = " + result);
                        break;
                    case "multiplication":
                        result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
                        Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + " * " + secondNumber + " = " + result);
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
                        Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + " " + stringOperation + " " + secondNumber + " = " + result);
                        break;
                    case "division":
                        result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
                        Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + " / " + secondNumber + " = " + result);
                        break;
                    case "^":
                        result = Math.Pow(firstNumber, secondNumber);
                        Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + " " + stringOperation + " " + secondNumber + " = " + result);
                        break;
                    case "exponent":
                        result = Math.Pow(firstNumber, secondNumber);
                        Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + " ^ " + secondNumber + " = " + result);
                        break;
                    case "%":
                        result = firstNumber % secondNumber;
                        Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + " " + stringOperation + " " + secondNumber + " = " + result);
                        break;
                    case "modulus":
                        result = firstNumber % secondNumber;
                        Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + " % " + secondNumber + " = " + result);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.Write("Choose a valid option");
                        break;
                }
            } while (true);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you feel that multidimensional arrays are particularly well suited to this task? Are you willing to contemplate the possibility that they aren't?

Comment: What did you tried yet? I do not see any case for memory option. What exactly are values you want to store and why you want to use multidimensional array? Note If you have 2 cases which have same body you can place them like this: 

`case "+":
 case "addition":
//do what you want`. You don't need to have same bodies multiple times in your switch

Comment: Yeah that was my bad. I sometimes over complicate my code

Comment: That´s OK, you are learning. It was just a little hint to make your code nicer. It is not a complication :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with something like this. Design a simple class to store history, which should contain the two numbers and the operation. Something like this:

```
public class CalculationHistory
{
    public double firstNumber { get; set; }
    public double secondNumber { get; set; }
    public string stringOperation { get; set; }

    public CalculationHistory(double firstNum, double secondNum, string op)
    {
        firstNumber = firstNum;
        secondNumber = secondNum;
        stringOperation = op;
    }
}
```

You can probably maintain a collection of these and restrict them to 10 or any other number as per your requirement. A Queue will be better suited if you want to only maintain a limited number of iterations.

```
Queue<CalculationHistory> history = new Queue<CalculationHistory>();
```

Every time you do an operation, be sure to add it to the queue.

```
history.Enqueue(new CalculationHistory(firstNumber, secondNumber, stringOperation));
```

And probably add a condition somewhere that checks if the Queue has exceeded `n` items and then `.Dequeue()`'s as required.

PS: In your code, you might want to combine the `case` statements like this instead of having separate ones for the same operation.

```
case "+":
case "addition":
    result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    Console.WriteLine(firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber + " = " + result);
    break;
```

Answer (score -1):

@degant's answer leads to a correct solution, specifically from an object oriented view.

However since you seemed interested in implementing the problem with arrays,  here's a very simple example without *any* regard to efficiency or [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

```
// the number of history expressions to maintain
static readonly int MAX_HISTORY = 10;

// allocate the history as an array of objects (i.e. anything).
// this makes it easy to store multiple types (double, string, etc). 
static object[][] history = new object[MAX_HISTORY][];

// track the number of *valid* expressions in history.
static int historyCount = 0;

// add something to the history
static void historyAdd(double a, string op, double b)
{
    // make sure historyCount never exceeds MAX_HISTORY
    historyCount = Math.Min(historyCount + 1, MAX_HISTORY);
    // shift all expressions over 1 to make room for the new expression.
    // if the array is full, the oldest expression is removed.
    Array.Copy(history, 0, history, 1, historyCount - 1);

    // create a 1x3 array to hold the expression in slot 0, 
    // which was reserved by the preceding array shift         
    history[0] = new object[3];
    history[0][0] = a;
    history[0][1] = op;
    history[0][2] = b;
    // shorthand to do the above: history[0] = new object[] { a, op, b };
}
// demo the history
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        historyAdd(r.NextDouble(), "+", r.NextDouble());

    Console.WriteLine("History:");
    for (int i = 0; i < historyCount; i++)
    {
        object[] expression = history[i];
        Console.WriteLine("{0}) {1} {2} {3}", i + 1, expression[0], expression[1], expression[2]);
    }        
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Please note this is employs [boxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx), which I generally avoid.